# I am not getting Table Rows. Kindly anyone help me?

Tags: cleos

[image: I have attached Code and output. have a look on it.]

[image: This is output]

Everything is working perfectly, the data is stored in it, smart contract deployed successfully,  compilation and generation of Abi everything is okay but when I call "Cleos gettable" it returns table without any rows.

Comment: get table takes three arguments `contract`, `scope`, and ,`table`. Make sure you are passing everything correctly.

Comment: Please post code and text in text form, not as pictures. The pictures are non-searchable, non-copy-pastable, and, in most cases, harder to read. All of which stands in the way of quality answers, let alone the question's continued usefulness.

Comment: Down voted.  Please add code to support future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Although your code is not easy to read you should not post the images. But as far as I understand by your code you have a problem with scope, pass the correct scope while getting your table. I think you should get the table like this 
`cleos get table blessed blessed student`
 Usually, your scope is your account name by which you set the contract.
Have a look at this article: https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-use-table-information-on-eos-smart-contracts-de68f7231b62

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share your abi file? I guess that your json property "tables": [..]" in abi file is empty.

One more thing:
"**//@abi table**" should be changed to "**//@abi table** {name of the table} **i64**". 
That thing tells to compiler to add table to abi file.